# INSERT ... SELECT on a huge MySQL table

Tags: mysql, select, insert, bigdata

I have isolated MySQL 5.5 with a huge table inside ( 3.5Tb of data and yes, it is only 1 table ).

The goal is to copy a half of this table into another one on the same server. How to do that better and quicker? :

1) Just "INSERT INTO new_table SELECT * FROM old_table WHERE ..."  . 
What will be MySQL behavior in this case? I expect that connection to MySQL will be broken by time out, however the query itself should run until all data are copied.
Or the MySQL will be just crashed with such query?

2) Using the same "INSERT ... SELECT" but selecting by chunks ( for example by 10000 rows). This should be definitely safer but much slower I guess.

What is the best way? Thank you in advance!

Comment: do you mean in the same database you want to store the two tables?

Comment: @RohitGaikwad Yes I am copying table in the same database. The idea is to shrink the table and in the end get much smaller one.

Comment: what about primary keys have you thought on that?

Comment: @RohitGaikwad yes. Before insertion I will drop all indexes on new table. And then add them back in the end. My question is about query itself - are MySQL and Innodb able to handle such huge query at once?

Comment: normalize your data.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `SHOW TABLE STATUS`.  There are likely to be other bits of advice (in addition to normalizing) that should be done _in the same pass_.  (Changing datatypes, etc)

Comment: Also, see my suggestions on [_Chunking_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks) .

Answer (score 0):

I've used CREATE TABLE AS, see if this could help you as well:

[CREATE TABLE ... SELECT Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-select.html)